# Is It Unfair For A Business To Change Its Severance Package Policy During A Pandemic?

Tags: labor-law, south-africa

In South Africa could it be considered an unfair Labour Practice if the practice and policy within a company had been to pay two weeks severance pay for each year worked. Then when the Covid 19 pandemic broke and the company realised that it need to retrench a large number of employees and it changed the policy to pay the minimum severance package required in law which is one week.

Comment: Typically legislation does not address situations which are as unusual as the coronavirus crisis, but a serious risk of bankruptcy might allow a company to reduce its liability. What does the employment contract says regarding things such as "acts of god"?

Comment: @IñakiViggers The employment contract does not address "acts of god" at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unfair

The laws of Rugby are completely fair - each side can field 15 players and the referee is impartial and the sole arbiter of time and motion.

You get to pick the best team you can from your local club. I get to field the Springboks. All totally fair according to the laws of Rugby. Who wins?

This site and the courts don’t care about fairness - it only cares about what’s lawful.

### So, what’s lawful?

If it is part of your employment contract then it can’t be changed unilaterally.

If it’s just “policy” then it can.

Comment: The Sprinboks always win : ). Our employment contract states:- "Retrenchment will be conducted in terms of legislation and your employer's policy." So does that mean that the policy may be unilaterally changed.